# form submits even when I click cancel in confirm form submission dialog

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

This might be some stupidity from my part but I cant figure this out. Pls see the code below.

```
<%= submit_tag "Send Request", :class=>"btn btn-primary", onclick:"submit_form();"%>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function submit_form(){
  var email = document.getElementById('customer_email').value;
  return confirm("An email will be sent to "+email+" on behalf of your request. Proceed?");
    }   
</script>
```

The form submits even when I click cancel. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using "return submit_form();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try instead of

```
onclick:"submit_form();"
```

this:

```
onclick: "return submit_form();"
```

Comment: Ah yes, I don't know why I didn't see that. Thanks a lot mate. You saved my day. Sorry that I can't vote this up as my reputation is low

Comment: An explaination or a reference to why it works this way would be nice. Event propagation and stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Your cancel button should not be a type of `"submit"`